# When <ui:repeat> works for X but <c:forEach> works for Y

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

I use `<c:foreach>` in my jsf app to iterate over a list of people. I don't use `<ui:repeat>` because every person has its own tab (primefaces). JSF hero 'BalusC' already helped my out on this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052581/dynamically-generate-tabs-with-primefaces). Now I tried to save (postback) the data. This doesn't work with `<c:forEach>`, the approriate setter of the Person object gets never called. With `<ui:repeat>` it works. Obviously I haven't grasped the difference between the two tags so I would appriciate some enlightenment.

Thanks

Marcel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<c:forEach>` does not build JSF tree nodes on the server. You can see this directly in the html, the inputs do **not** have the usual long and distinct `id="j_12:customerTabPanel:j_34:customerName"`.

Please, read this:

https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat

Answer (score 6):

`<c:***>` tags are build-time tags, as `<ui:***>` are rendered-time tags. To get the difference between these two concepts, I recommand you to read the two links below:

- [`<c:forEach>` vs `<ui:repeat>`](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat)
- <s>[Why `<ui:repeat>` does not work?](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Projects/FaceletsFAQ#Why_doesn_t_my_c_if_ui_repeat_ui)</s> 
  *(editor's note (2013-01-03: dead link)*