# Access JSF Custom Tag's id

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, twitter-bootstrap-2

**TL;DR**
Is there something like composite's cc.clientId that will give me the id of a custom tag?

**Details:**
I'd like a custom tag that will render a label, a value, and an icon. When the icon is clicked, a Bootstrap modal is supposed to open up that will edit the value.

```
<ui:composition>
  <div> #{field.label}: #{field.value} 
    <a class="icon-pencil" data-target="#editForm" data-toggle="modal">
  </div>
  <h:form id="editForm" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" ...>
    ... there's an input here linked to field.value ...
  </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

I can use the tag with `<my:editor />`. When I do so within a ui:repeat, an id is prepended to the editForm so that it renders with id `j_idt104:editForm`. So I need to modify the data-target to include the id.

This would be really easy with a composite component because I have access to the id via cc.clientId:

```
data-target="\##{cc.clientId}\:editForm"
```

However, I can't get it to work with a custom tag because I don't know of an EL expression (or something) that will give me access to the id. I could probably wait until after the page is loaded, then use jQuery to inspect the id and set the data-target after the fact, but I was hoping for a more pure-JSF solution.

I'm using JSF 2.1 and Bootstrap 2.3, at the moment.

Comment: Tagfiles doesn't do that. They are on the contrary to composite components no `NamingContainer`s. Isn't that autogenerated ID actually coming from an `<ui:repeat>` around `<my:editor>` or so?

Comment: it is, actually. i'm repeating the editor for items in a list in the backing bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer seems to be no. [BalusC says](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers) you should replace things like custom tags with "normal" JSF components. In this case, that would mean using the composite component.

If you're deadset on using custom tag, I worked around the issue (with lots of help from the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15661176/640030)) by using an index in the form's id:

I replaced the `ui:repeat` with a `c:forEach` that has access to the item's index:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item" varStatus="status">
  <my:editor index="#{status.index}" ... />
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

And in the custom tag, I used the index in the `data-target`:

```
<tr>
  <td>#{label}: #{value}</td>
  <td>
    <a data-target="\#editForm-#{index}" ... ></a>
    <h:form id="editForm-#{index}" ... >
      ...
    </h:form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The only catch is that `c:forEach` is a build-time construct (see details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4223053/640030)), which is a problem if you need any render-time data (like if you build information up in preRenderView). If you do, then you're better off using `ui:repeat` with a custom component, and relying on the `cc.clientId`.