# How to make a primefaces dynamic toolbar

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working with PrimeFaces 3.1.1 since last week and it seems to be an excellent visual component framework. I'm doing a migration from Richfaces and trying to get everything working only with Prime and JSF2 (2.1.6 version).

My problem comes with a dynamic toolbar I have to implement. Some of the operations are integrated directly on the toolbar (commandButtons) and other operations have some suboperations inside, so I have to do a menuButton with the operation name and add every single operation here like a menuitem. Here is my code:

```xhtml
<h:panelGroup id="Texto_Header" layout="block">
        <h:form>
            <p:toolbar>
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <!-- Operaciones de aplicación -->
                    <ui:repeat value="#{logedBean._apps}" var="opBean">
                            <!-- OPERACION PRINCIPAL EJECUTABLE -->
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{opBean._Clickable}">
                                <p:commandButton ajax="true" value="#{opBean._Nombre}"
                                    action="#{opBean.actionOperationClick}" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <!-- OPERACION PRINCIPAL CON SUBOPERACIONES -->
                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!opBean._Clickable}">
                                <p:menuButton value="#{opBean._Nombre}">
                                    <ui:repeat value="#{opBean._subOperaciones}" var="opBean2">
                                        <p:menuitem ajax="true" value="#{opBean2._Nombre}"
                                            actionListener="#{opBean2.actionOperationClick}" />
                                    </ui:repeat>
                                </p:menuButton>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

My problem is I'm getting only the first operation components, it renders the commandButtons correctly and their actions are working well, however in the case of "#{!opBean._Clickable}" I get a menuButton with the name, but no menuitem inside. It looks like the embeded ui:repeat iteration is not being well done.

I have tried the same chance using *c:foreach*, *c:choose* and *c:otherwise* tags and in this case I get the menus visually well done, commandButton actions are working well too, but when I click in a menuItem it's saying that opBean2 is not recognized... However as I have said before, I prefer to use JSF tags exclusively. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: By the way, both logedBean._apps and opBean._subOperaciones are Collections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to get it work with jsp iteration tags and changing the actionListener attributes of menuitem tags for action attributes. Here is my code:

```xhtml
    <h:panelGroup id="Texto_Header">
    <h:form>
        <p:toolbar>
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <!-- Operaciones de aplicación -->
                <c:forEach items="#{logedBean._apps}" var="opBean">
                    <!-- MAIN OPERATION -->
                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{opBean._Clickable}">
                        <p:commandButton value="#{opBean._Nombre}"
                            action="#{opBean.actionOperationClick}" update=":linkPanel" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <!-- OPERATION WITH SUBOPERATIONS -->
                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!opBean._Clickable}">
                        <p:menuButton value="#{opBean._Nombre}">
                            <c:forEach items="#{opBean._subOperaciones}" var="opBean2">
                                <p:menuitem value="#{opBean2._Nombre}"
                                    action="#{opBean2.actionOperationClick}" update=":linkPanel" />
                            </c:forEach>
                        </p:menuButton>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**EDITED**

It has to be with jsp tags because [Primefaces Toolbar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/toolbar.jsf) doesn't have specific model to be integrated in a backing bean in order to be built during page rendering. So it has to be in page build. Similar was happening with [Primefaces TabView](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewHome.jsf) but they managed to solve it and now tabView has a built-in iterator. Take a look to a related cuestion.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057370/1199132

**EDITED 2**

New PF MenuModel seems to solve this kind of issue at all. It will be able to build the menu programatically at the bean. Available from 4.0.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2594

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to nested `ui:repeat` elements. I've also encountered a similar issue before by nesting them and didn't figure out how to get `ui:repeat` work correctly.

Currently I'm using Richfaces `a4j:repeat` for this issue. I haven't seen any incidents of using the UI components of Primefaces with `a4j` elements.